# Does receiver of initWith... methods take ownership - memory mgmt

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

toNewbie question: Could someone help me understand if the receiver of an initWith.... method take ownership of the returned object and should manage it.
For example:

```
NSString *msg; //could be used to hold some data, then
[msg initWithFormat: @"some text"]; //do I need to do a retain or is the method returning an auto-released string object
```

Just trying to get my head wrapped around methods that don't use alloc explicitly

Comment: Unless you are targeting iOS 3 or OS X 10.5 then consider using ARC for your projects. You then won't have to worry about memory management.

Comment: This code either does nothing or crashes; `msg` isn't a valid object, so you can't send messages to it. If you're creating an instance, then you send `alloc` to the class and `init...` to the result of that. That's Cocoa convention. If you've seen something else, then post that _actual_ code. Otherwise, read the [Memory Management Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) and look at [memory management questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+memory+management+alloc&submit=search) here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods with `init` in the name are generally called in conjunction with `alloc`, as in:

```
MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

`alloc` returns an object with a +1 retain count, so you shouldn't need to retain it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm aware of alloc/init combo, but if I called initWith... convenience initilizer, does it increment the retain count or do I have to manually call retain [[msg initWithFormat:@"some text"] retain]; Please advise.

Comment: @badboy11: There's no such thing as an `initWith...` convenience initializer. You have to send a message to the class first to get an instance, like `[Weeble weebleWithWobble:w]`.

Comment: I think I am slowly starting to understand. I looked at Programming in Objective-C 2.0 by Stephen Kochan. If I call [msg initWithString: @"some text"]; on an already declared NSString pointer, then it is autoreleased, unless I explicitly call the class using alloc or copy/retain the string.

Comment: @badboy11: It's not autoreleased. You're asking entirely the wrong question. You are _not allowed send an `init` message_ to anything but the result of `alloc`.